# Socket.io can't find the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io in my server. But it gives me this error: `GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
Here is my server code:

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const taskRouter = require("./routers/tasks.js")

app.use( "/" , taskRouter)

io.on('connection', function (socket) 
{
  console.log("Connected!")
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is on port ${PORT}`);
  });
```

Here is my pug code:

```
extends ../header2.pug
block unique-css
    include ../../public/css/mentor/chat.css
block unique-content
    .main
        h1 Hello World!
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
    script
        include ../../public/js/mentor/chat.js
```

Here is my client-side javascript code:

```
var socket = io()

socket.on('connection', function (data) {
  console.log("helloworld");
});
```

And the problem is when I try to use socket.io I get this errors in browser `GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`, `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`. The second error is pointing to the first line of frontend js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use server.listen(port)

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const taskRouter = require("./routers/tasks.js")

app.use( "/" , taskRouter)

io.on('connection', function (socket) 
{
  console.log("Connected!")
})

//changes below
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is on port ${PORT}`);
  });
```

And in the client-side you don't require this code. Delete this.

```
socket.on('connection', function (data) {
  console.log("helloworld");
});
```